# Accessing SSL Private Key From a Servlet

Tags: java, apache, servlets, ssl

I'm running Apache Tomcat locally and have installed a self signed certificate using OpenSSL. I also have a servlet running.

What I want to do is the following:
The servlet takes in POST parameters and will echo back the parameters signed using the PrivateKey of the server. That is, treat the input parameter as an integer and raise it to the power of the private key.

The problem: Is it even possible to access the server's PrivateKey from the servlet? If deployed on some other hosting, it's probably not possible to access it directly. So is there any way that I can request that the server 'sign' some piece of data with its Private key?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the way the container is configured. In the general case, the SSL configuration of the container will not be accessible by a servlet it contains. For example, in Apache Tomcat, that connector's SSL configuration can be completely independent of the settings accessible by a servlet. (In addition, SSL may be handled by APR or an Apache Httpd front-end, for example, which won't have much to do with the Java keystore configuration).

You would probably be able to gain access to the keystore if they are configured using the `javax.net.ssl.*` properties. However, that's not necessarily the way the `SSLContext` of the server connector is configured from. It's not generally a good idea to pass those parameters on the command line either in a production environment.

What you may be able to do is to load the keystore used by the container, from your servlet, but you'd have to know where it is, in advance. In addition, I would suppose that a hosting service would run Tomcat with a security manager turned on, which may prevent you from doing this.

Note that you could use your own keystore, shipped within your webapp (it can even be loaded from the classpath as a resource stream). Whether this keystore will contain the same private key as the one use by the server's SSL layer is up to the server's administrators (if they let you have it).

Answer (score 2):

If I were writing a weberver I'd go to great lengths to prevent code from reading from the certificate store - I certainly wouldn't provide an API call for it!

Usually the cert is stored as a file on the webserver's filesystem (not always) but for a site with any serious security on it, this would be encrypted and require a passphrase to decrypt. Since you are using a self-signed certificate its probably not encrypted - just import the cert from the file into the keystore.

Comment: You said it! An application that has access to the webserver's private key could use it to do nasty stuff like a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: @David Gelhar, indeed, you need to trust the application enough if you allow it access to the private key of your server, but this might be the case if the server is dedicated to that application (and you trust whoever deploys it in the same way as you trust the server admin). If you don't trust the webapp dev/deployer with the key, sure, don't let it access it. I'm not sure how that would be considered a "man-in-the-middle" otherwise, since it's rather the server/container that's in the middle of the client and the webapp anyway.

Comment: What I mean is that the app developer could use the server's private key in the course of a man-in-the-middle SSL attack where a 3rd party device intercepts SSL traffic intended for the server (e.g., by DNS spoofing) and eavesdrops on the traffic (or modifies it). The app itself wouldn't be the "man in the middle", but its access to the private key would be what would allow the impersonation to succeed. Yes, this is less of an issue if the server is dedicated to a single application.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Java keystore you can access it from your servlet, as long as it knows the keystore location and password.

Answer (score 0):

Servlet can access any data on your machine including keys. The only situation can be when Apache and Tomcat are running from different user names and keys are locked to be accessed only by Apache user name. You can do a trick in this case as su a process under Apache user name and read the file.