# javamail sends via tls on workstation but not on server

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-mail, keystore

I can connect and send myself email just fine from my workstation

Workstation Versions:

- Java   - **1.6.0_21**
- Tomcat - **6.0.29**

However on the Server I get an error:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 
  smtpa.state.ak.us, port: 465 
  (java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: 
     Error constructing implementation 
     (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, 
      class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl))
```

at the Bottom of the stacktrace is the following section

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.getCacertsKeyStore(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl.getDefaultTrustManager(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        ... 76 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
        ... 88 more
```

The Server is running:

- Java   - **1.6.0_18-b-07**
- Tomcat - **6.0.28**

Javamail is bundled with my Web Application, and is version **1.4.3**

**Edit:**

For completeness sake I upgraded the bundled *Javamail* to **1.5.0-b01**
I'm still getting the same errors.

`keytool -list -keystore <path-to-default-java-keystore>` with the default java keystore password works on both systems.

**Further Edit:**

After some more digging I found this SO Question: [Accessing Tomcat's configured KeyStore and TrustStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772597/accessing-tomcats-configured-keystore-and-truststore)

I added some logging statements to my application:
I get the same result on my Workstation as I do on on the server.

```
10-25@12:20:30 DEBUG [statements] TextEmail - javax.net.ssl.trustStore: null
10-25@12:20:30 DEBUG [statements] TextEmail - javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword: fedizPass
10-25@12:20:30 DEBUG [statements] TextEmail - javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType: null
10-25@12:20:30 DEBUG [statements] TextEmail - javax.net.ssl.keyStore: null
10-25@12:20:30 DEBUG [statements] TextEmail - javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword: fedizPass
10-25@12:20:30 DEBUG [statements] TextEmail - javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType: null
```

if you look carefully the default password isn't returned, and neither is the trust Store.
I have **Fediz-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT** configured with a custom *trustStore* for *WS-FEDERATION* My Fediz code is using the **Spring-Security** plugin.  All of that works properly. I have a second application deployed on both my WorkStation and Test Server that uses it as well. It also works properly and can send files via FTPS to another server.  Also If it's supplying the wrong password in the SystemProperties, then why does it work on my workstation but not the Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Bill Shannon I was able to get it to work.

I ended up extending `MailSSLSocketFactory`, listed in an example in [Javamail - SSLNotes](https://javamail.java.net/docs/SSLNOTES.txt)
I followed the [JSSE Reference - Creating Your Own X509TrustManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#X509TrustManager)
I used it to add a Backup TrustManager that grabs the default *KeyStore* from `System.getProperty("java.home")` and passes in the default password. It attempts to set that `X509TrustManager` up as a fallback in case the default one created by `MailSSLSocketFactory` fails to validate the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your Tomcat configuration is selecting a different keystore with a non-default password?

Comment: How can I tell if it's pointing to a different Keystore?  I tried adding `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"` to Catalina.sh and that didn't help.

Comment: See the Debugging section in [SSLNOTES.txt](https://javamail.java.net/docs/SSLNOTES.txt).  Perhaps some of the additional JSSE debugging output will help.  You can also try printing out the javax.net.ssl.trustStore property from within your program to make sure it's being set as you expect.

Comment: I tried setting the various debug options. None of them seemed to print.(I just realized my Log4J settings probably squashed it.) However printing the javax.net.ssl.*store* properties, as specified in my edit helped me realize that something was setting the password to access the truststore wrong. So I ended up wiring a TrustManager together based on `MailSSLSocketFactory`. Probably not the best approach, but effective.