# tomcat get all trust certificates

Tags: ssl, tomcat7, truststore

I have a small security application with server and client certificates which is running in a tomcat 7. Each client has an own certificate.

In the webapp I want a tab with all known trusted certificates aliases because each client have to report all X minutes. 
If the client do not report after X minutes the server has to mark this client.

So my idea was to get all trusted certificates from the truststoreFile which is defined in the Server.xml of the Tomcat, because I have to know all clients/certificates which are registered.

My problem is that I do not find any api to get all certificates, which the tomcat will trust.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, are you sure your truststore will (always) contain the client certs? The "official" (X.509/PKIX) way of client authentication aka client certificate(s) is to have a CA (or several CAs) issue certs to the clients; then your server doesn't need to trust the client certs individually, only the CA(s). Such a CA could be a public CA, an enterprise one, or one you (or your group/division/whatever) runs just for your server. Only for selfsigned client certs is it necessary to have them individually in the server truststore.

Second, it doesn't appear possible for webapp (servlet) code to get the connector configuration, possibly as a security feature, see [Accessing SSL Private Key From a Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048892/accessing-ssl-private-key-from-a-servlet) .

But, **if you do have all the certs** in a truststore file **and can locate that file** (usually JKS), then:

- use `KeyStore.getInstance(String)` to obtain a keystore object of the correct type (JKS)
- create a `FileInputStream` for the file, and feed it to `ks.load` (and then close it; try-resource can do this for you). If you don't know the password use `null` and you can still access certs (but not privatekeys, and only for JKS)
- use `.aliases()` to get a list of all entries in the store
- if there can be both trustedcerts and privatekeys in this file (i.e. it isn't *just* a truststore file) check each alias with `.isCertificateEntry(alias)`
- you now have the aliases, which are the names specified when you (or someone) imported each cert to the truststore, but is not necessarily the same as client's actual name in the cert
- If you want (any of) the name field(s) *in* each cert, call `.getCertificateEntry(alias)`, cast to `X509Certificate`, and call `.getSubjectX500Principal()` then `.toString()` or one of the `.getName()` overloads and parse or examine the results as desired

Finally, since you want to track requests *using* each cert *by* alias, for each request get the certs used as in [Read out incoming certificate in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945013/read-out-incoming-certificate-in-tomcat) then look up the leaf cert i.e. `chain[0]` with `.getCertificateAlias(Certificate)`. Keep track for each alias the time of the last request and you can identify any "missing" ones.

Javadoc for KeyStore is at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html